# compilng C code to run on a system without OS?

Tags: c, x86, operating-system

How can I compile C source code that uses standard functions like printf to run on a system without OS?

I tried using GCC to link statically but it seems I'm missing something. Can someone please explain how this can be done with GCC?

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler might have some information for you.

Comment: I'm curious, did you get it running at all without OS? I think it will still need OS for most basic functions like launch, exit, memory allocation etc. I might be wrong however.

Comment: how are you running  gcc without OS ?

Comment: "...but it seems I'm missing something": yes, you are missing the OS which manages devices for I/O, loads programs, manages memory etcetera...

Comment: Errm guys?! If you never bothered to look up how it would work to do some bare-bone programming or cross-compiling, why do you down-vote and give funny comments?

Comment: @user2225104 What ? So you know a way to get printf working without OS ? printf can't work without all the OS display drivers and stdout management. Making it work means rewriting it entirely, and it totally misses the point.

Comment: I wanted GCC (using Linux as host) to generate flat binary. Is it possible to statically link the library that contains printf and then have a sort of simple loader coded in assembly to load the output file and have it run ?

Comment: You need to build your own "runtime library" of course. If you program bare-bone, that is typically a static lib or a few source files you link to your bare-bone-main program. As a starting point you use some printf implementation and simply re-write the line(s) of code where it calls fwrite() to call your own output function, which is less work than one would expect. See yourself, for example here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/printf/printf.c. If you do that kind of thing for as long as it takes that bash is running, you can call it LINUX.

Comment: @user3479526 The problem is that printf rely on the OS, so statically linking and using it without OS won't work. On the other hand, functions like sprintf don't need the OS. If you want to print some text, your best bet would be to use sprintf to format, then use a routine to display text. You will need fonts and graphic functions to do that, though.

Comment: user2225104 Thank you so much..things are much clear to me now. The link you provided doesnt work though. Thank you so much the other people who post positive comments.

Comment: Well, an OS has to be made running without an OS, so of course it's possible to run code from a C compiler without an 'OS'.  IIRC, printf() outputs to putchar(), which must be able to reference an output stream driver.  How control gets to the start point of the crt is hardware-dependent, but not normally awesomely difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> without OS

is difficult. your example `printf()` implies an output to a display. And this is (besides many other things) a task of an operatong system. Even the BIOS is an OS, and is capable of displaying text (and responding to keyboard presses).

So you have to decide, which minimalistic OS you are running your program on, and then you can crosscompile against that OS.

Answer (score 0):

If by "without an OS" you mean you are compiling to run on an embedded platform then printf() will have no meaning for you because the platform does not have a standard output, which is where printf() is directed to on an OS (this is why it is in the stdio header).

Embedded platforms usually come with other means of outputting or monitoring data or states such as changing GPIO pin states, sending data to a communications peripheral (which will require you to write a driver for that) or maybe your program loader/IDE has some expression watch or feedback support.

Some embedded device manufacturers supply compilers for specific devices and in this case may come with the standard C library, but configuration will still be required to use printf().